# Kafka brokers on IaaS with changing host

Tags: apache-kafka

I have my Kafka brokers running on a proprietary cloud IaaS platform. The brokers will be relocated to a new host every week or so. When a broker is relocated, it restores its partition data from other brokers. If all brokers die, I loose all data.

I have a load balancer in place that round-robins between the brokers for bootstrapping.

When a client connects (via the load balancer), the Kafka client will then fetch a list of brokers and store this to connect to.

If all the brokers are relocated whilst the client app is still running, the client app will be unable to reconnect to the cluster. It does NOT use the bootstrap server to re-query for a new list of brokers, it'll keep trying to connect to the list of brokers it had from when the app first started.

How can I get around this problem? Do I change the broker config for `advertised.listeners` to add the fixed load balancer host:port to each of the brokers? Will I run into a problem because every broker has the same host:port set for this config?

Comment: For how long did you run the program, before you concluded that it will not try to requery for a new list of brokers?

Comment: @JavaTechnical - can replicate doing the following: 1. Start client app. 2. Stop all brokers at the same time. 3. Brokers will start on other servers. 4. Client app won't be able to re-connect to the cluster

Comment: The metadata refresh which when happened should fetch the new broker details, provided the load balancer IP is the same as what you've given in your bootstrap servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try decreasing the metadata max age to refresh metadata frequently. The newly available broker resolved through the DNS should give the active broker list.

`metadata.max.age.ms` - Default value is 5 mins (Confluent Platform)

> The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of
> metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to
> proactively discover any new brokers or partitions

Also, check:

`metadata.max.idle.ms`

> Controls how long the producer will cache metadata for a topic that's
> idle. If the elapsed time since a topic was last produced to exceeds
> the metadata idle duration, then the topic's metadata is forgotten and
> the next access to it will force a metadata fetch request.

Reference: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html

Also, you have commented that:

> The brokers will be relocated to a new host every week or so. When a
> broker is relocated, it restores its partition data from other
> brokers. If all brokers die, I loose all data.

Ideally, though you can relocate the broker processes for whatever reason, relocating the data frequently isn't recommended, rather you can have your Kafka data stored in some distributed storage that can survive broker relocations (provided it is within the data locality requirements).

Even if you don't have the provision to use distributed storage, you must atleast try to relocate the data too or use [mirror-maker/confluent replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/migrate-replicator.html) for replication.

I am not sure how you will lose data when all brokers die because data is always stored persistently on disk. Unless, you have employed some volatile storage (or) the disk where your data is persisted crashes, your data should mostly remain as it is and should be recoverable on broker restart.

If you are using docker/kubernetes environment, make sure you have configured persistent volumes.

Comment: I have no persistent storage available, so rely on at least one broker being available to not loose data. This will help in most circumstances. One thing that can happen is that all brokers are taken offline at the same time - which this won't protect against...I want client apps to reconnect/recover automatically at this point.

Comment: If the list you have given in the bootstrap servers points to the load balancer which will be available, then it should use that to fetch the metadata after sometime. If the load balancer IP changes, then there is pretty much nothing to do about it, afaik.

Comment: I just did a test. Started App. Restarted brokers. Waited > 5 mins to account for the metadata refresh. Still unable to connect. If I restart the App, it connects just fine. Based on the logs, its continually attempting to connect to the previous brokers ip/port

Comment: Can you enable kafka debug logs and see what is happening?

Comment: it looks like its trying to request the metadata from the old brokers (the ones that were killed). The bootstrap server is set to the loadbalanced URL.

Comment: Does the load balancer url point to the new brokers?

Comment: Yeah it does, I can see it points to the new brokers. There is nothing in the logs to indicate it's attempting to fetch metadata through the load balancer. Kafka 2.7.1 if it matters. Based on the logs, only the first metadata request goes to the load balancer, every subsequent request for metadata is via one of the brokers it got from the first request